# Compare string entries of columns in different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, both with different number of rows.

df1 has a column 'NAME', a short string; and df2 has a column 'LOCAL_NAME', a much longer string that may contain the exact contents of df1.NAME.

I want to compare every entry of df1.NAME with every entry in df2.LOCAL_NAME, and if df1.NAME appears in a particular entry of df2.LOCAL_NAME, I want to create add an entry in a new column df2.NAME_MAP = df1.NAME. If it doesn't appear in the long string df2.LOCAL_NAME, the corresponding entry in df2.NAME_MAP will be df2.LOCAL_NAME

For now, efficiency is not an issue. Here are sample datasets.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME" : ['222', '111', '444', '333'],
    "OTHER_COLUMNS": [3, 6, 7, 34]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "LOCAL_NAME": ['aac111asd', 'dfse222vdsf', 'adasd689as', 'asdv444grew', 'adsg243df', 'dsfh948dfd']
})
```

df1:

| NAME | OTHER_COLUMNS |
| --- | --- |
| '222' | 3 |
| '111' | 6 |
| '444' | 7 |
| '333' | 34 |

df2:

| LOCAL_NAME |
| --- |
| 'aac111asd' |
| 'dfse222vdsf' |
| 'adasd689as' |
| 'asdv444grew' |
| 'adsg243df' |
| 'dsfh948dfd' |

The goal is to create another column in df2 called NAME_MAP which has the value of df.NAME if that string is contained exactly in the larger df2.LOCAL_NAME string. df2 would now look like this:

| LOCAL_NAME | NAME_MAP |
| --- | --- |
| 'aac111asd' | '111' |
| 'dfse222vdsf' | '222' |
| 'adasd689as' | 'adasd689as' |
| 'asdv444grew' | '444' |
| 'adsg243df' | 'adsg243df' |
| 'dsfh948dfd' | 'dsfh948dfd' |

Then I can join the two dataframes on NAME_MAP:

| LOCAL_NAME | NAME_MAP | NAME (from df1) | OTHER_COLUMNS (from df1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'aac111asd' | '111' | '111' | 6 |
| 'dfse222vdsf' | '222' | '222' | 3 |
| 'adasd689as' | 'adasd689as' | NaN | NaN |
| 'asdv444grew' | '444' | '444' | 7 |
| 'adsg243df' | 'adsg243df' | NaN | NaN |
| 'dsfh948dfd' | 'dsfh948dfd' | NaN | NaN |

How do I go about trying to do this string comparison in two datasets of different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to solve it

Create a df with cartesian product of both dataframes such as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907526/merge-dataframes-with-the-all-combinations-of-pks

```
cp = df2.assign(key=0).merge(df1.assign(key=0), how='left')
```

Keep only the lines where NAME is in LOCAL NAME (just print cp after that so you understand what's done)

```
cp['key'] = [1 if x in y else 0 for x,y in zip(cp['NAME'],cp['LOCAL_NAME'])]
cp = cp[cp['key'] == 1].drop(['key'], axis=1)
```

Merge, and fill the ones without combination by the local name

```
df2 = df2.merge(cp, how='left', on='LOCAL_NAME')
df2['NAME'] = df2['NAME'].fillna('')
df2['NAME'] = [y if x == '' else x for x,y in zip(df2['NAME'],df2['LOCAL_NAME'])]
```

Result :

```
    LOCAL_NAME  NAME        OTHER_COLUMNS
0   aac111asd   111         6.0
1   dfse222vdsf 222         3.0
2   adasd689as  adasd689as  NaN
3   asdv444grew 444         7.0
4   adsg243df   adsg243df   NaN
5   dsfh948dfd  dsfh948dfd  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by looping through the rows using `apply` and using `str.contains` to check if the `LOCAL_NAME` column contains the value from the `NAME` column:

```
(
    df1
    # check which LOCAL_NAME values are related
    .assign(matches = lambda x: x["NAME"].apply(lambda y: df2.loc[df2["LOCAL_NAME"].str.contains(y), "LOCAL_NAME"].tolist()))
    # make sure each row only has one key in the case that there are multiple matches found (is this possible?)
    .explode("matches")
    # join with the second dataframe to get the NAME_MAP column
    .merge(df2, how="right", left_on="matches", right_on="LOCAL_NAME")
)
```

This will give the following output dataframe:

| NAME | OTHER_COLUMNS | matches | LOCAL_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 6 | aac111asd | aac111asd |
| 222 | 3 | dfse222vdsf | dfse222vdsf |
| nan | nan | nan | adasd689as |
| 444 | 7 | asdv444grew | asdv444grew |
| nan | nan | nan | adsg243df |
| nan | nan | nan | dsfh948dfd |

Comment: Appreciate the response, I'll try it out!